# Method parameter passing from view to controller play-framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have this method in my application controller:

```
public static Result searchJourney(String address) {
    return ok(
        views.html.searchResults.render(Journey.searchByAddress(address),journeyForm)
        );
}
```

Which takes a string as an argument and passes this string to a model method *searchByAddress*.  The search by address method returns a list of my model objects that are the result of a query. This is then used to populate a form.

```
public static List<Journey> searchByAddress(String address) {
    return find.where().ilike("start_loc", "%"+address+"%").findList();
}
```

The problem I am having is getting the address argument from a view form. This is what the view looks like:

```
@main("Journey Search", "search") {
<body>  
        <form>     
        Search for journeys starting in a town/city:
        <input type="text" name="arg"></br>
        <input type="submit" onsubmit="@routes.Application.searchJourney("@arg")" value="Search">
        </form>
    }
```

All routing is working as expected but I can't seem to get to pass this argument to the controller method. When I enter a value in the textbox the URL updates to display my input:

```
http://localhost:9000/search?arg=testvalue
```

But the results page never gets rendered as I would expect.

Update:

```
<form action="@routes.Application.searchJourney(arg)">     

    Search for journeys starting in a town/city:
    <input type="text" name="arg"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

Without the quotation and @ symbol around the arg I am getting `not found: value arg` errors.

The results HTML to be rendered

```
@(listJourneys: List[Journey], journeyForm: Form[Journey])

  @import helper._

  @main("Search Results", "search") {
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Starting Location</th>
            <th>End Location</th>
            <th>Participant Type</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <!--<th>User</th>-->
             </thead>
              <tbody>
            </tr>

          @for(journey <- listJourneys) {
                <tr>
                  <td>@journey.id</td>
                  <td>@journey.start_loc</td>
                  <td>@journey.end_loc</td>
                  <td>@journey.participant_type</td>
                  <td>@journey.date</td>
                  <td>@journey.time</td>
                </tr>
          }
              </tbody>
      </table> 
    }
```

Comment: can u please answer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433509/populating-drop-down-with-the-values-from-database-in-play-frame-work/29434643#29434643

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
@routes.Application.searchJourney(arg)
```

instead of

```
@routes.Application.searchJourney("@arg")
```

BTW, why are you setting it in `onsubmit` atribute? isn't it better to use common form's `action` for this purpose?

**Edit**

Ach, now I understand in general you **can not** build reverse routes with undeclared arguments, or arguments coming from the user's input in HTML form. They **must** exist in the moment of the view rendering and must have some value.

For getting what you showed ( `http://domain.tld/search?arg=val` ) where `val` becomes from user's input you need to use a route with `arg` as optional param with some default value (in your case most probably empty string will be good:

```
GET  /search      controllers.Application.searchJourney(arg: String ?= "")
```

action:

```
public static Result searchJourney(String arg) {
    return ok(
        searchResults.render(Journey.searchByAddress(arg),journeyForm);
    );
}
```

and then you need set an `action` of the form to this route without `arg` and also set its method to `get`:

```
<form action="@routes.Application.searchJourney()" method="get">
   ...
</form>
```

You can also do not set any params in the route:

```
GET   /search      controllers.Application.searchJourney
or
POST  /search      controllers.Application.searchJourney
```

And then use for an example `DynamicForm` to bind fields from request:

```
public static Result searchJourney() {
    String arg = form().bindFromRequest.get("arg");
    // perform some basic validation here
    return ok(
        searchResults.render(Journey.searchByAddress(arg),journeyForm);
    );
}
```

Comment: I made the changes and modified my post. I think without the "@" the arg value cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, this has resolved my issue.