# Populating Drop down with the values from database in play frame work

Tags: java, scala, playframework, ssms

I am new to play frame work and i am finding it bit difficult.
 i am retrieving list of client names from data base and populating it to a dropdown ,here is my client.java code

```
   package models;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
public class Client extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1932214701504374792L;
    public static String ClientName;
    public static ArrayList<String> Clientdetail= new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> PopulateClient() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433","SUMEET","sumeet");
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            String Sql = "select * from client";
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ClientName = rs.getString("ClientName");
                Clientdetail.add(ClientName);
               }

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException |SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return(Clientdetail);

    }

}
```

Here is My application.java code

```
package controllers;

import models.Client;

import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {


    public static Result index(){

        return ok(index.render(Client.PopulateClient()));
    }

}
```

and here is my index.scala.html

```
    @(ClientDetails: java.util.ArrayList[String])

@main("ADMS") {

   <center>
    <form id="select">
   <a>CONSULTANT</a>
       <select name=Consultant>
           <option value="lokesh">Lokesh</option>
           <option>@ClientDetails</option>
           <option>Vidyasekar</option>
           <option>Abhishek</option>
           <option>Naveen</option>
           <option>Nanda</option>
       </select>
     <table border="1">
       <tr>
       <td width=50px>Client</td>
       <td width=50px>Project</td>
       <td width=50px>Task</td>
       <td width=50px>Date</td>
       <td width=50px>Consultant</td>
       <td width=50px>Role</td>
       <td width=80px>Is Billable</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>@ClientDetails</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
   </center>
}
```

main.scala.html

```
@(title: String)(Content: Html)


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
   </head>
    <body>
    @Content
    </body>
</html>
```

Can some one help me with this? i need to populate the dropdown with the array value and the data that is getting populated is just brackets   -->   "[]"

Comment: @(title:String)(ClientDetails: List[Client]) it should be @(title:String)(ClientDetails: java.util.List[String])

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti i tried the code u told and it dint work

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti yeah the suggestion u gave works but displays [] can u show me a way to display the list in dropdown? i have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework provides template helper library which gives functionality to build select dropdown with options and selected value.
It's pretty simple to use once understood properly.

@helper.select() method in view takes various parameters related to a input field of select type. 1st parameter is form field, since here we don't have any form we can create a temporary form and create a new field inside with name Consultant[as this will the value of name attribute of select field].
2nd parameter will be map of options in which key and value, corresponds to value of option tag and text enclosed in option tag respectively.

Controller code

```
package controllers;

import models.Client;

import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {


    public static Result index(){

        return ok(index.render(Client.getClientDetails()));
    }

}
```

Model Code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;

import play.db.ebean.Model;
public class Client extends Model {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1932214701504374792L;
    public static String ClientName;
    public static HashMap<String, String> Clientdetail= new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static HashMap<String, String> getClientDetails() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433","SUMEET","sumeet");
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            String Sql = "select * from client";
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ClientName = rs.getString("ClientName");
                Clientdetail.put(ClientName,ClientName);
               }

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException |SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return(Clientdetail);

    }

}
```

View Code : index.scala.html

```
@(ClientDetails: java.util.HashMap[String, String])

@import helper._

@main("ADMS") {

   <center>
    <form id="select">
   <a>CONSULTANT</a>
   @select(Form.form()("Consultant"),           
       options(ClientDetails),
       'value -> "clientName1"[any value that should be selected by default])
     <table border="1">
       <tr>
       <td width=50px>Client</td>
       <td width=50px>Project</td>
       <td width=50px>Task</td>
       <td width=50px>Date</td>
       <td width=50px>Consultant</td>
       <td width=50px>Role</td>
       <td width=80px>Is Billable</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>@ClientDetails</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
      </form>
   </center>
}
```

Comment: i have updated the data and added ClientID in `Clientdetail.put(ClientID,ClientName);`   now where do i place ClientID and ClientName in   `@select(Form.form()("Consultant"),           
       options(ClientDetails),
       'value -> "clientName1"[any value that should be selected by default])`

Comment: i tried the exact code u have put and it is printing just { } in the ui and nothing else

Comment: use inspect element to check whether it is creating select element or not

Comment: if select element is rendered and options are not rendered in that case check the data you are passing in ClientDetails

Comment: how do you handle onChange here ? like when data is changed populate i  need to populate another dropdown so how do u post the selected value back yo Application.java?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, unfortunately Play's templates system is Scala based so you'll have to map over the your @ClientDetails:

```
@ClientDetails.map { clientName =>
  <option>@clientName</option>
}
```

If you return more complex objects it could look more like this:

```
@ClientDetails.map { client =>
  <option value="@client.id">@client.name</option>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Right, you need to convert List<String> into String with the method I showed you. Either that or provide a toString method for List<String>.

Comment: i tried the code u sent but it din work how can u put ClientName when it is local to Client.java ? and how can i loop all the elements in ClientDetails and put htem as option to Select